# How to attain this OneUI like icon shape in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, geometry, android-compose-textfield

How can I attain this shape in Jetpack Compose? Or How do people at Samsung should have attained this shape?
I tried with Squircle shape. But it's not working.

[image: OneUI Icon shape]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default shape in your manifest just change the rounded-icon to the one you want…

Here is the issue I have come across.. you can set the icon shape but it will not show correctly on a live device. Here is why, it doesn’t show correctly.

In the device you can set your default icon to whatever. So if your icon is square and the default in the device places it as round, then your icon will default to round.

So your style of icon shape is irrelevant because it depends on the user’s device whether or not the default is one or another.

You can test this on your phone in settings and when you change the default icon to your icon shape it will show, as well as every other icon, but if you change the shape then all the icons change shape.

For the inner icon that’s just the design of their logo. It was designed that way. It’s just an image in the placeholder. So if you want the inner design of that icon you would need to design it…

However the core icon you don’t really have control over it. All my apps on google play I don’t even worry about the icon shape anymore. It’s now up to the user’s preferences in the device.